# How to POST json from c# through localhost and get the data in php?

Tags: c#, php, json

I'm trying to do a simple program with a very simple UI.

Just a button in a c# windows form, when i press the button it encodes a simple array to Json and upload it to http://localhost, and then get the json data in PHP.

This is my code now in c#

```
private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:8080/SemesterProject/index.php");
    httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
    httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";

    using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
    {
        string json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(new
        {
            user = "Foo",
            password = "Baz"
        });

        streamWriter.Write(json);
        Console.WriteLine("Console.WriteLine(json);");
        Console.WriteLine(json);

    }


    var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        Console.WriteLine("Console.WriteLine(result);");
        Console.WriteLine(result);

    }
}
```

And this is my code in PHP:

```
<?php
$post= file_get_contents("php://input");
$decodedjson=json_decode($post,true);
var_dump($decodedjson);

?>
```

at PHP output i get
       'NULL' 
and in c# output i get

```
Console.WriteLine(json);
{"user":"Foo","password":"Baz"}
Console.WriteLine(result);
array(2) {
  ["user"]=>
  string(3) "Foo"
  ["password"]=>
  string(3) "Baz"
}
```

After this i need to post the data from PHP to phpMyAdmin database

Comment: So you're getting a valid response in .NET from your PHP application?

Answer (score 0):

Try simple way:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Net;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
    public Form1()
        {
        InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        using (var client = new WebClient())
            {
            var postData = new NameValueCollection();
            postData["user"] = "Foo";
            postData["password"] = "Baz";
            var response = client.UploadValues("http://localhost/xxx.php", postData);
            var data = Encoding.Default.GetString(response);
            // Console.WriteLine("Data from server: " + data);
            MessageBox.Show(data);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

// php file xxx.php

```
<?php
echo json_encode($_POST);
?>
```

In your message box will dosplay json string

Comment: do i need to write this?
              

                var response = client.UploadValues("https://localhost:8080/SemesterProject/index.php", postData);

Comment: First code send data to file api.php  then in php file you can write: echo json_encode($_POST);

Comment: this is the output:

"C:\xampp\php\php.exe" "C:\xampp\htdocs\SemesterProject\index.php"
[]
Done.

Comment: for wat you want send json you can send only post data

Comment: See now and test it.

Comment: it pops a windows with the text (without toString())
but in php it still [ ]

Comment: but if you need save something on php side you need add some script

Comment: change url and file name from my example

Comment: which script? thats what i need to do

Comment: You need show in google save to file for example: file_put_contents('file.txt', json_encode($_POST));